# What committees in Congress handle tax code modifications?

Tags: united-states, taxes

The current administration is [planning a tax code overhaul which is being released soon](https://www.tampabay.com/news/business/republicans-to-unveil-broad-tax-cuts-wednesday-put-off-tough-decisions/2338889).

What committees in Congress handle proposed legislation that changes the tax code?

Answer (score 1):

In the House,

- [Ways and Means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_House_Committee_on_Ways_and_Means) is the main one.
- [Budget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_House_Committee_on_the_Budget) also matters.
- [Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_House_Committee_on_Rules) touches every bill a little, as they set the rules for voting.

In the Senate,

- [Finance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Senate_Committee_on_Finance) is the main one.
- [Budget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Senate_Committee_on_Budget).

If it goes to conference,

- [Joint Committee on Taxation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Congress_Joint_Committee_on_Taxation); note that the members come from Ways and Means and Finance.

Note that the rules on committees are somewhat fluid.  So [other committees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_congressional_committee#Current_committees) might also ask to review the bill, for example if it changes taxation that specifically targets an industry under their purview.  These are the committees that touch every tax bill in some way.